What advantages and disadvantages soldiers of anarchist areas might have against invading state-sponsored standing armies?
What advantages and disadvantages soldiers of anarchist areas might have against invading state-sponsored standing armies?
In what way anarchist armed forces might differ from state-sponsored standing armies?
One possible disadvantage of anarchist forces is their limits when it comes to escalation and the commitment to total annihilation of the enemy. A state-funded military may just wipe out the enemy by using indiscriminate means, e.g. with atomic bombs, but the soldiers contracted by the anarchists may be limited in what they can do, given that their sponsors might be unwilling to wipe out the entire states knowing that there might be some oppressed anarchists living on the territory of the enemy. Such soldiers
may even be funded by such anarchists. Where can I read more about it?
The research I've done includes relevant chapters from
Individual Liberty by Benjamin Tucker but have not found the answer there.

Probably a better fit for Worldbuilding or History SE.

I assume that by anarchist regions you mean regions whose parts are controlled transiently by whatever alliance of persons happens to have the most access to compulsive force?

@g s It may be an institution finance by donations it may be an alliance too. The term anarchist region rules out so-called military rule (be it the rule aristocracy or oligarchy).

See Worldbuilding - Could one build an effectively anarchist military structure?

https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/168249/could-one-build-an-effectively-anarchist-military-structure. Black Elk describes The Battle of Little Bighorn this way: Crazy Horse whipped Three Stars. The Lakota warriors had no State sponsored army. They rallied behind Crazy Horse and defeated the US Army led by a three-star general. In general State sponsored militaries have clear advantages but might not dominate the Anarchist opponent depending on specific factors in each social group.

